# Optimization in R?

Tags: r, optimization, weibull

I tried to fit Weibull distribution to my Wind data.
Weibull has 2 parameter : k (shape parameter) and A (scale parameter).

I have used `fitdist` function from `fitdistrplus` package. and estimated the A and k. but I should consider wind power density (wpd) as additional condition. It is defined by `0.5*1.225*v^3` v is my wind speed.
 I have to consider `wpd(1)=wpd(2)`. This means that I use the defined formula for wpd, on my measurement data and make the average, this is `wpd(1)`.
Then I estimate the Weibull and compute `wpd(2)` like :
`sum(0.5*1.225*wind speed bin*Weibull)`. If `wpd(1)` and `wpd(2)` are not equal, then I have to change the estimated A and k parameter of Weibull to make `wpd(2)` exactly the same as `wpd(1)`. I do not know how should I do it in R ?

```
head(data)
            TimeStamp MeanWindSpeed60.0 Direction60.0 TurbInt60.0 MeanWindSpeed80.0 Direction80.0 Temperature80.0
2 2010-04-15 16:50:00              9.96         255.3      0.2167             10.07         257.1            17.6
3 2010-04-15 17:00:00             10.77         262.6      0.1762             11.19         266.1            17.8
4 2010-04-15 17:10:00             10.00         267.8      0.2637             10.01         272.0            17.8
5 2010-04-15 17:20:00             12.21         250.9      0.0982             12.33         252.3            17.0
6 2010-04-15 17:30:00             11.79         253.8      0.1409             11.94         257.8            17.0
7 2010-04-15 17:40:00             11.56         253.1      0.1175             11.80         255.5            16.7
  TurbInt80.0 MeanWindSpeed84.0 Direction84.0 Temperature84.0 TurbInt84.0 MeanWindSpeed110.0 Direction110.0
2      0.2232             10.09         257.1            17.6      0.2228              10.20          257.1
3      0.1535             11.21         266.1            17.8      0.1531              11.35          266.1
4      0.2632             10.04         272.0            17.8      0.2626              10.16          272.0
5      0.0849             12.35         252.3            17.0      0.0848              12.47          252.3
6      0.1342             11.97         257.8            17.0      0.1339              12.12          257.8
7      0.1087             11.82         255.5            16.7      0.1084              11.97          255.5
  Temperature110.0 TurbInt110.0
2             17.6       0.2203
3             17.8       0.1512
4             17.8       0.2593
5             17.0       0.0839
6             17.0       0.1322
7             16.7       0.1071


c=data %>% 
  dplyr::select(TimeStamp, matches("MeanWindSpeed|Direction"))%>%
  tidyr::gather(key = "key", value = "value", -TimeStamp) %>%
  tidyr::extract(col = key, into = c("variable", "height"), regex = "([:alpha:]+)([:digit:]+)") %>%
  tidyr::spread(key = variable, value = value) %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  mutate(wsbin = cut(MeanWindSpeed, breaks = seq(-0.5, 25.5, 1), labels = seq(0, 25, 1)),
         wdbin = cut(Direction, breaks = dir.breaks, ordered_result = TRUE)) 

c$wdbin = cut(c$Direction, breaks = dir.breaks, ordered_result = TRUE)
levels(c$wdbin) <- dir.labels

c=c %>%
  dplyr::group_by(height) %>%
  dplyr::filter(MeanWindSpeed >0) %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  dplyr::mutate(meanWind = mean(MeanWindSpeed)) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(wpd = mean(0.5*1.225*(MeanWindSpeed^3))) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(shape =fitdist(MeanWindSpeed,distr = "weibull")$estimate[1], 
       scale =  fitdist(MeanWindSpeed,distr = "weibull")$estimate[2]) %>%
  dplyr::group_by(height, wdbin) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(sector_shape = fitdist(MeanWindSpeed,distr = "weibull")$estimate[1], 
                sector_scale = fitdist(MeanWindSpeed,distr = "weibull")$estimate[2])

    d= c %>%
      dplyr::group_by(height, wsbin) %>%
      dplyr::summarise(meanws = mean(MeanWindSpeed), nov = n(),shape= mean(shape), scale= mean(scale))  %>%
      dplyr::group_by(height) %>%
      dplyr::mutate( weib_fit= dweibull(as.numeric(as.character(wsbin)),shape = shape, scale = scale)) %>%
      dplyr::mutate(wpd2 = sum(0.5*1.225*(as.numeric(as.character(wsbin))^3)*weib_fit)) %>%
      dplyr::mutate(nov.abs = sum(nov)) %>%
      dplyr::mutate(freq = nov / nov.abs)
```

Comment: Please provide a full reproducible example, including a sample of your `data`.

Comment: Can you provide `data` as executable code (such as with `dput`)?